# iOS: Browse and send file from FileSystem to PHP server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am new to iOS development. In My application, I have to browse one file and send that file to PHP server. Can anyone tell me how could i accomplish that functionality?
(File may be document , image file)

Comment: iOS has no user accessible file-system.

Comment: @Nitin is there any way to do that?

Comment: Web service of php is used as mediator..

Answer (score -1):

You can only access document directory of the app. If your file is being saved in document directory then you can send it on your server.To upload a file on server you can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) 
And use the code

`ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg"/* Your file path here*/ forKey:@"photo"];`

You cant directly browse the file system but you can get the list of files and folders present in document directory and show this list to the user in table view. when user click on a perticular file get the path of that file and upload it to the server. It worked for me like a charm.

Comment: how to import ASIFormDataRequest class,in my project.

Comment: See the official site and follow the steps given over there.